# How to write Code Analysis (FxCop) rule to prevent a method call

Tags: .net, fxcop

How do I write a code analysis tool for vs2008 to prevent a specific framework call, such as GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() or Application.DoEvents()

I tried overriding the VisitMethodCall in my custom rule, but I cannot figure out what the Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.MethodCall parameter really has in it. Could not find example on the web.

Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://nervoustych.com/blog/CategoryView,category,Coding,FxCop.aspx

This person used the "normal" override of Check() method, then in the case of a Method, loops through each instruction looking for calls, then matches the call with a full name.

Comment: this link appears dead, is there an updated link?

Comment: Here is the dead link from the waybackmachine: https://web.archive.org/web/20090909101353/http://www.nervoustych.com/blog/CategoryView,category,Coding%2CFxCop.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Replace `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.String)` with the method signature that you are trying to find and prevent.

```
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
        if (member is Method)
        {
            var callees = new List<Method>(Callees.CalleesFor((Method)member));
            foreach (var callee in callees)
            {
                if (callee.FullName == "System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.String)")
                {
                    Problems.Add(new Problem(GetResolution()));
                }
            }
        }

        return Problems;
    }
```

Comment: Will this also pick up methods that override HtmlEncode in derived classes?

Comment: @Tharwen, this will only find calls to the specified signature: System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.String)

Comment: @slolife Does this also works for constructors? If I want to prevent the use of the constructor for `TimeoutException`, will replacing `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.String)` with `System.TimeoutException.TimeoutException(System.String)` be enough?

Comment: @OscarVasquez, that I don't know.  I am sure it would work for constructors, however, I don't know what the syntax is for them.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a [Debugging book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Debugging-Microsoft-NET-2-0-Applications/dp/0735622027)  that I think  that had a chapter on FXCop rules and discussed how to write one. For the life of me I cannot find my copy. And I suspect you'll need reflector

Answer (score -2):

An alternative to the mess of writing FxCop rules would be to use the tool NDepend. This tool lets write **Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries** [what we call CQLinq](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

> How do I write a code analysis tool for vs2008 to prevent a specific framework call, such as GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() or Application.DoEvents()

For this particular need, the simple following CQLinq rule is enough (notice the usage of [AllowNoMatch()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.Reserved.CQLinq.ExtensionMethodsCQLinqDependency~AllowNoMatch.html) to make this rule work in any situation):

```
// <Name>Don't call these methods</Name>
warnif count > 0
from m in Methods 
where m.IsUsing ("System.GC.WaitForFullGCComplete()".AllowNoMatch()) ||
      m.IsUsing ("System.GC.WaitForFullGCComplete(Int32)".AllowNoMatch()) ||
      m.IsUsing ("System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()".AllowNoMatch())
select m
```

CQLinq queries can be edited live in VisualStudio, and offer instant result, with result browsing facilities:

[image]

Let's precise that rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

Answer (score -3):

While it's no match for NDepend, or even FxCop itself, I've just posted a very lightweight approach here, that works well for simple things like preventing calls to particular methods: http://activesharp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20ActiveSharp%20as%20a%20Unit%20Test%20Tool

Comment: You'd be better pasting the relevant code into your answer so we can evaluate it in a self-contained fashion